# generating hash table using perl script

Tags: xml, perl, perl-data-structures

I am trying to create hash table using perl. please can help me because i am begginer to perl and i am reading but i am not able to implement. i need to create hash table from below code data number as a key and description as value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you googled? StackOverflow is not "do my job for me" site.

Comment: sorry i posted what i am tried still now and can you help me what i ahve to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a common data format like XML, don't try to do this manually by reading the file line by line and parsing it yourself. Instead, use a perl module to do it for you.

The [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) module may be sufficient for you to start with. I think the module is already installed on your system by default.

```
use strict;   # tip: always use strict and warnings for safety
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

my $data = XMLin(\*DATA); # loads up xml into a hash reference assigned to $data
print Dumper $data;       # uses Data::Dumper to print entire data structure to console

# the below section emulates a file, accessed via the special DATA file handle
# but you can replace this with an actual file and pass a filename to XMLin()
__DATA__
<DATA>
    <!-- removed -->
</DATA>
```

### UPDATE

Now that the xml file is loaded into a hashref, you can access that hash and organise it into the structure that you want.

```
# loads up xml into a hash reference assigned to $data
my $data = XMLin(\*DATA);

# organise into [testnumber => description] mappings
# not sure if 'Detection' is what you meant by 'description'
my %table = ( $data->{Testnumber} => $data->{Detection} );
```

The problem with this scenario is that the xml data only contains a single testnumber, which is all this code handles. If you want to handle more than that, then you'll probably need to loop over an array somewhere. I don't know how the xml data will look like if there is more, so I don't know where the array will be.

Comment: I tried but i am not getting like hash table . i need to get trouble code nuber and their description below for searching purpose and aslo for next usage.

Comment: What are you getting? Any error messages or clues about the current problem? What do you get when you print the dump?

Comment: i am getting the hole xml file, but i need to disply like test number and their description in one one table. like all testnumbers in one column and regarding test number description(<dtc>..to..</dtc>) in one column.

Comment: Thanks for your updates, its given an idea to me and i implemented like that by using while loop and i created hash table. thanks for your help and i accepted your answer.@stevenl.

Comment: hi can you delete the data in the above reply please it may cause problem to me@stevenl